# Using DataVisualization Chart library shows "ghosts" points WPF MVVM C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-visualization

I have a program which wrote in WPF MVVM and I have a *View* which using DataVisualization Chart library (DVC.dll) to shows graphs on my *View*.

In my *ViewModel* I have several *ObservableCollections<>* which contains DataPoints that reflects on the graph just right , but after several minutes of use the graph starts to shows "ghosts" points of previous charts and won't refreshed until I restart the whole program.

I try to use Clear() function for each Collection before it updates with a new points, and added a small Thread.Sleep() delays when changing data in the Collections, but nothing helps.

Any solutions?

[image]

**View:**

```
<DVC:Chart Title="Cross Section" Background="LightSteelBlue" Height="385" >
    <DVC:Chart.Series>
        <!--Ground Line-->
        <DVC:LineSeries IsSelectionEnabled="True" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=X}" 
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPointOnGraph, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                        DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Y}" ItemsSource="{Binding HydroPoints, BindsDirectlyToSource=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                        TransitionDuration="0">
            <DVC:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DVC:LineDataPoint}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="SaddleBrown" ></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="2" />
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=Coordinate}" />
                    <Setter Property="Template" >
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="DVC:LineDataPoint">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                                    <Canvas>
                                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" 
                                                   Text="{Binding Path=PointNote, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                                    </Canvas>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DVC:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
            <DVC:LineSeries.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="DVC:LineSeries">
                    <Canvas x:Name="PlotArea">
                        <Polyline x:Name="polylinee"
                          Points="{TemplateBinding Points}" 
                          Stroke="SaddleBrown" 
                          Style="{TemplateBinding PolylineStyle}" />
                    </Canvas>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </DVC:LineSeries.Template>
        </DVC:LineSeries>
    </DVC:Chart.Series>
</DVC:Chart>
```

**HydroPoints.cs (The Model file has the same properties with set\get with OnPropertyChanged event)**

```
public class HydroPoint : BusinessObjectBase
{
    public int PointID { get; set; }
    public int StationID { get; set; }
    public int SectionID { get; set; }
    public DateTime SectionMesurDate { get; set; }
    public Single X { get; set; }
    public Single Y { get; set; }
    public string PointNote { get; set; }
    public Single PointRoughnessCoefficient { get; set; }
}
```

**HydroMainViewModel.cs**

```
    public ObservableCollection<HydroPoint> HydroPoints
    {
        get { return _hydroPoints.OrderBy(x => x.X).ToObservableCollection(); }
        set
        {
            if (_hydroPoints == value)
                return;
            _hydroPoints= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("HydroPoints");
        }
    }


    public void SetSelectedSectionByConboBox()
    {
        if (RPointsList != null && RPointsList.Count >= 0)
            RPointsList.Clear();
        if (HydroPoints != null && HydroPoints.Count >= 0)
            HydroPoints.Clear();             

           [....]

       HydroPoints = Repository.HydroPointsRepository.HydroPoints.Where(X => X.StationID == CurrentStation.SerialCode && X.SectionID == SelectedSectionID && X.SectionMesurDate == _selectedMesurDate).ToObservableCollection<HydroPoint>();
       RPointsList = Repository.HydroPointsRepository.RPoints().Where(X => X.StationID == CurrentStation.SerialCode && X.SectionID == SelectedSectionID && X.SectionMesurDate == SelectedSectionMesurDate).ToObservableCollection<HydroPoint>();

         [....]
    }
```

Comment: @YvetteColomb I've edit the code, shorted it almost by half to be more understandable.

Comment: You are right, but one time its ItemSource is HydroPoints collection, and the other time its RPointsList collection. You think that this is what cause the problem?

Comment: Does the problem occur with both series? Otherwise remove the one thats working and only keep the faulty series. Also, if the problem can be reproduced within a single series, remove the other one even if its faulty, because the solution for one should be enough.

Comment: @grek40 I've tried to remove one series of <DVC:LineSeries from the XAML, but unfortunately the problem still occurs after several data changes (with a ConboBox that replace the data collection each time).
It seems that the graph on the view stopped to refresh, or not refreshed fast enough, there is a way to make the view's graph to refresh it self? (MVVM).

Comment: As commented, if the problem is reproduceable with a single series, you should change your question to contain only a single one... thats what a **minimal** example is all about - don't pack things into the example that are not needed to produce the problem.

Comment: @grek40 OK, I edited my Xaml code here removed one <DVC:LineSeries />. any more suggestions?

Comment: @Orionlk lets reduce the XAML a bit more... does the problem still occur with the following: `<DVC:Chart><DVC:Chart.Series><DVC:LineSeries IndependentValuePath="X" DependentValuePath="Y" ItemsSource="{Binding HydroPoints}"/></DVC:Chart.Series></DVC:Chart>`? I think we will need more information on the code that updates the items, but lets first make sure that no xaml details are at fault.

Comment: @grek40 The problem still occurs after isolated the xaml code like you suggested, and now it behave interesting: when I'm changing selections in my view's comboBox, it firstly draw the line, and the point are fades in to appears in the line. When I'm changing selection the line changes, the older points are fade out and the new ones fades in. After some time, some points are stay steady on the graph, and when I'm changing selection, just the line refreshed but without any points in it.

Comment: @YvetteColomb whee!  Side note, OP, calling `Thread.Sleep()` in your UI thread is only going to lead to sadness. How will your UI update when it's thread sleeps?

Comment: @YvetteColomb All the code in that particular program is run on the UI thread without and other background threads, so the UI just freeze a little (100ms) and go on. I'll remove the Sleep() because I've added this for testing while trying to solve the problem, but it doesn't help.

Comment: @Orionlk if the problem still occurs with the really minimal xaml, then you definitely need to provide some context (code behind, other UI, ...) so others will be able to reproduce your issue. The minimal xaml has no room for errors on its own.

Comment: @grek40 OK, I'll add some code behind to my question

Comment: @grek40 I've tested it alot in the past 2 hours, and it seems that the problem somewhere in the XAML, I have this <ControlTemplate TargetType="DVC:LineDataPoint"> which contains a <Grid> inside and that inner Grid is the object that stay as "ghosts" on screen after changing selections. I have added a "Refreshed" button on my program that clears and delete all the Collection's data, and when it happens all the lines + points cleared from the graph, EXCEPT those that become to "ghosts". There is a way to refresh the canvas or the grid in the XAML?

Comment: @Orionlk there are two possible ways to solve this: (1) do it yourself or (2) edit your question with **all relevant** information. You had so many helpful comments and so much time, still the question is not answerable because you hold back information and you didn't create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which should ideally be in the question when you first write it before any editing.

Comment: @grek40 Thank you for trying to help! I've added some code behind to my question, if you need another information let me know, I'll added too.

Comment: @Orionlk you commented about `<ControlTemplate TargetType="DVC:LineDataPoint">` being at fault... where is it? Honestly, I won't ask for more information again, just provide a minimal working example of the problem.

Comment: @grek40 <ControlTemplate TargetType="DVC:LineDataPoint"> it is already in the xaml code that I've posted yesterday, in the middle after <Setter.Value>.

Comment: Ok, you completely confused me now... I thought the problem is reproduceable with the minimal `DVC:Chart` that doesn't even contain any custom templates... as you commented *"The problem still occurs after isolated the xaml code like you suggested"* - please clarify.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being cleared enough, "....after isolated the xaml code..."  means that I've removed the second <DVC:LineSeries /> that has in the xaml (aka binding  RPointsList), and as I explained in my primarily question this "ghosts" appears after 20-30 changes of data (The HydroPoints collection gets different points of data  each time), and when it happens you can see in the .JPG file - what stays permanently on the graph is the items the defined in the <Grid /> that appears under the <ControlTemplate TargetType="DVC:LineDataPoint"> line in the xaml tree.

Comment: The whole `HydroPoints` handling is a very big mess (worst: the getter creates a new collection each time), but still: forget everything about your project, create a new project, put only your question code into it, reproduce the error. You can't? Well at least I can't, because it's far from being a complete example.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I'll try to create a new project and isolated the code to work and try to reproduce the problem. if I'll success I'll update here. Thanks again.